# How to count the number of zeros in each position of the sublist using python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have 4 sublist in the list below of length 38, i want to count the number of 0 on each position. please how do i do it?

[[01100000100000000001100001001110100000],[01100000100000000001100001001110100000],
[01100000100000000001100001001110100000],
[01100000100000000001100001001110100000]]

The first index of the four sublist is 0000, hence the number of zero is 4.
the second index of the four sublist is 1111, hence the number of zero is 0.
That is how i want to count for the 38 positions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question if your numbers are lists or strings. Assuming they're strings (otherwise just use [bin()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=bin#bin)), I'd use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) to separate each position then simply [count()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) the `'0'`:

```
numbers = ['01100000100000000001100001001110100000',
           '01100000100000000001100001001110100000',
           '01100000100000000001100001001110100000',
           '01100000100000000001100001001110100000']
[digits.count('0') for digits in zip(*numbers)]
```

Comment: The solution you provided worked as i wanted. good job @FrancisColas